# How to convert an colored image into density monochrome one?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I've searched for long time and nothing comes back. All I can find is converting images to narrow gray scale thresholds. and it looks awful.
All I want is to convert an image to density monochrome(maybe wrong words, please correct me, I really don't know how to describe that..). Just like mono laser printer does. It uses different densities of black dots to present different gray levels.

I'm using C++ and OPENCV now. Appreciate anyone can help:-)

===============
Update:

This kind of images called 'halftone'. Search engines will be more helpful with a proper search word.
Here's something:
[Halftoning with OpenCV](https://github.com/timfeirg/Basic-image-manipulation-in-OpenCV-under-C--/blob/master/2-Halftoning-11311030-%E5%88%98%E5%A5%95%E5%A4%AB.mdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right term is 'dithering'.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering) is a description of one of simple dithering algorithms.

[Неre](https://github.com/kehribar/Dithering-OpenCV/blob/master/main.cpp) seems to be one of the implementations of it for OpenCV in C++. Maybe not the most efficient one, but one that could get you started.

Comment: Thanks your links are useful. And I suddenly found that kind of images called halftone. :-)

Comment: @HerlinDrew: You can also read here for a nice introduction to halftoning and dithering: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/355

Answer (score 0):

`OpenCV` doesn't support monochrome images internally. Only grayscale is supported and it is stored as `grayscale PGM (P2)`.

It may be useful. https://sdaps.org/Documentation/Scanning/